# How do I avoid Keynote reducing image quality?

Tags: keynote

I want to create an animation in Keynote for a proof of concept. So I create a custom 16:9 document with 1440 x 810 pixel size. Then I add an image with a 1440 x 6395 pixel size. When I first add the image it's downsized so that it doesn't stretch beyond the slide height, but I click the **Original size** to have it fill the width (and stretch beyond the height).

The problem now is that even though I've clicked **Original size**, I'm quite sure the image isn't actually its original size, at least not in resolution.

When I set the presentation in full screen this is part of what I see:
[image]

When I look at the same area of the image in Finder Preview this is what I see:
[image]

So you see, the image in Keynote is undoubtedly reduced in quality.

Does anyone know how I avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

After some research I found that this is a problem that has appeared since Keynote 6, and is probably due to iOS compatibility (limiting PNG original quality to stick up to 4096px height).

A tip however was to import your image as PDF instead, then Keynote won't downsample it.

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: This trick worked for me - thanks for sharing :-)